# How to read text values from xlsread in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

I've read an Excel file in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and put the values in an array with this statement:

```
 [x,y]=xlsread('file_name.xlsx');
```

When I type [x,y], I see the data of the Excel sheet. Something like this that was inserted in the Excel file:

```
'ask' 'question'

'hello' 'hi'

'apple' 'fruit'
```

I want to access each column or row, and I want to put every column in a specific array. How can I parse the values and put it in another array? I also need to know the number of rows. How can I do it?

Comment: Your syntax doesn't make much sense. Have you looked at [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) for `xlsread`? This question isn't really clear enough to provide useful answers. What are the data types in your spreadsheet? How is your data formatted? What are your sort criteria? Without knowing these, all we can really do is point you to the [indexing documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Comment: i dont have any sort, i just want to access the elements of each row,and types of my data is char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the xlsread function, it extracts a numbers array and a text array. If the values in your spreadsheet are only non-number text (e.g. 'cat', 'dog89') but not numbers (e.g. 100, 0.2), then the text values will be stored in the `txt` array, and `num` will be empty.

`[num,txt] = xlsread('spreadsheet.xlsx');`

If you look at `num`, you'll see it is an empty array. If you print out `txt`, it will print out the cell array containing the values.

The number of rows is:
`numrows = size(txt,1);`

To access a specific row and column value (e.g. row 3, column 5): `specvalue = txt{3,5};`

To put each column into a separate cell array (e.g. put column 4 into its own cell array): `newcellarray = txt(:,4);    %Note the use of () vs. {}`